# How to get current page margins using iText API

Tags: pdf, merge, itext

I have this requirement to merge two pdf documents and set the specified margin in the resultant pdf document. Is there a way to get current page margin form either PdfReader or PdfImportedPage? I would like to get these measurements to decide whether to transform or scale the input page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really isn't such a thing as far as the PDF format is concerned.  You've got a bunch of bounding boxes that may or may not be defined on a given page.  The only required box is the Media Box:

Media Box:  The 'page size'.  The size of the media this PDF page should be printed on.

Crop Box: The size of the finished page.  Any difference between media and crop will be cut off in a post processing step.  Defaults to the media box.

Art Box:  Encompasses "the page's meaningful content".  Defaults to the crop box.

Trim Box & Bleed Box:  Similar to the crop box, but nebulously different unless you happen to be a professional print house concerned with things like "Rated Speed".

Unless you're lucky with the Art Box (and I'd be shocked), your only real option is to parse the contents of each page (with the classes in com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.*) and DEDUCE the margins yourself.  This is likely to be error prone.

OTOH, if application that originally made the PDF might have embedded its layout information in the PDF, in which case you'd need to find out how they did it on an app-by-app (or even version-by-version) basis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps:  http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=280
It's in Java, though; not sure what context you're in.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this example and for some reason I am seeing an NPE with a PDF document with tables and Images in them. I am wondering whether this TextMarginFinder could be used for all kinds of PDF documents. I also found that this TextMarginFinder is a new addition to the iText API.